# Dynamic Web Project option missing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

The "Dynamic Web Project" option for a new project in Eclipse does not appear in the list. Also, the "web" folder does not exist. Am I missing a module from installation?

I am running Eclipse Helios.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ try "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". It probably is also possible to update your eclipse via the marketplace (Help-> Eclipse Marketplace) but I didn't now the plugin name

Comment: I am using the Eclipse for  Java Developers  but I'll update it to EE.

Comment: You can visit this url & follow the steps given there. http://coding-for-dummies.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-get-dynamic-web-project-option.html

Answer (score 49):

Go to Eclipse->Help menu->Install new software choose the Web, XML, Java EE plugin and install it.

Comment: you have to choose working with environment drop down, otherwise it will not appear XML, Java EE plugin.

Comment: Follow these steps for any version of eclipse, just need to chose correct web location from in Work with area:- For eclipse Neon :- the site is Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon     , for kepler :- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler    and so on.

Comment: with Oxygen I can not see the option : Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers when I check : Web,XML,Java EE and...

Answer (score 22):

1. Open Eclipse and go to help->Install new software.. option available.
2. Click the down arrow available in **work with** field and select following
   link
           **Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler**
3. Now select checkbox with name **Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise

   Development** click next -> next -> accept the licence requirement -> finish.
4. Wait for sometime till plugins got downloaded.
5. **Restart the eclipse** and now go to file->new->other->web and you will see
   **project** will be available.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone facing problem with eclipse(Oxygen), this answer is for those.

Help --> Install New Software-->
place this URL in work with field

Eclipse Oxygen: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/

Eclipse Photon: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/

Select the list of software's which do you want to update and complete normal update process. Once, installation completed you have to restart the eclipse. So, you are able to create the Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: I can not see   Eclipse for JEE developers when I choose  the oxygen link you provided any idea why ?

Comment: Oxygen will support for JEE developers also. But, you have to install few plugins to support UI code like, JSP, HTML, JS and CSS etc.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is re-install your eclipse choosing the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" version that contains everything you could need to create a "Dynamic Web Project".

But if instead what do you need is a lighter eclipse to develop a Web Java application with aspectj, maven and Tomcat I recommend you to try this:

Steps for Eclipse Standard 4.3.2
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr2

1. Add "Web Tools Platform"
   http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler

   - Web Tools Platform (WTP) 3.5.2

     - Faceted Project Framework (required to install Java EE Developer Tools)
     - Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement (required to install Java EE Developer Tools)
     - Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.5.2 (dynamic web project)
     - Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.5.2 (JSP editor)
     - Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.5.2
     - JST Server Adapters (need it for Tomcat server adapter)
     - JST Server Adapters Extensions (need it for Tomcat server adapter)
   - Web Tools Platform (WTP) Patches 3.5.2

     - WTP Patches for org.eclipse.jst.commong.fproj.enablement.jdt
2. Add "AspectJ Development Tools" (if you need AspectJ)
   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/43/update

- AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.3

3. Add "Maven Integration for Eclipse" (if you need maven)

- Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi...

  - m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1

4. Add m2e for AJDT
   http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/

   - Maven Integration for AJDT 0.14.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on Help and then click on “Install New Software”.
2. In Work with paste this link: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/Kepler
   Change the link according to your Eclipse version, for example for the Eclipse 
   2020-03 the link would be http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03
3. Scroll down to find “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development” 
   option and expand it.

   4.Select the following three options under “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development”

   -Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

   -Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools

   -Eclipse Web Developer Tools
4. Click next and you would see that the software are installing. Wait for some time and then a popup would ask your permission to restart the Eclipse. Restart it and you would find the dynamic web project option under project list.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to  get this option when I installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Thanks free_easy

Answer (score 2):

I guess nowadays all specific versions are integrated into on installer.
So, you need choose "...for Enterprise Java Developers" option as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]

you must have installed IDE for java developer,so install IDE for ENTERPRISE JAVA DEVELOPERS as their is a common installer for eclipse these days.