# Dynamic Web Project option missing in RAD 9

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-rad

I am using RAD 9  and I could not find the Dynamic Web Project option.[Web options I have in RAD 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khedx.jpg)

I also tried to follow the steps mentioned in an existing thread:

[Dynamic Web Project option missing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587734/dynamic-web-project-option-missing-in-eclipse)

But when I tried to install Java EE Developer Tools under Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development I got the following message. [j2ee development tool already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ6iR.jpg)

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the `Web Project` option. IBM RAD has provided a wizard of its own.

Comment: Thanks for the hellp!!